# What could be the return type of List of json object in Angular 2 typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular

Here What could be the return type of getFiles()(other than any) what could be the specific return type ?

```
   @Injectable()
    export class NodeService {

        constructor(private http: Http) {}

        getFiles() {
            return this.http.get('./resources/data/cars-medium.json')
                        .map((res: any) => res.json().data);
        }
    }
```

cars-medium.json

```
{
    "data":[
        {"vin":"a1653d4d","brand":"VW","year":1998,"color":"White"},
        {"vin":"ddeb9b10","brand":"Mercedes","year":1985,"color":"Green"},
        {"vin":"d8ebe413","brand":"Jaguar","year":1979,"color":"Silver"},
        {"vin":"aab227b7","brand":"Audi","year":1970,"color":"Black"},
        {"vin":"631f7412","brand":"Volvo","year":1992,"color":"Red"},
        {"vin":"7d2d22b0","brand":"VW","year":1993,"color":"Maroon"}
           ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getFiles():Observable<Object[]> {
```

If you have an interface like

```
interface Car {
  vin:string;
  brand: string;
  year:number;
  color:string;
}
```

you can also use

```
getFiles():Observable<Car[]> {
```

Comment: Thanks @Gunter but when i  use .toPromise() and then() then it showing me error Promise<Car[]> is not assignable to Observable<Object[]> ?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code there that demonstrates exactly how you are using it?

Comment: thanks Gunter it worked for me:)
Actually i was trying with .toPromise() also and i changed return type of method to Promise<Car[]> and it worked Thanks!!!!